# Что такое database backup и хранит ли оно всю database информацию?

Tags: mysql

В Mysql  нужно перенести базу даннъх с записанной в ней информацией , не могу понять как  это сделать, нужно ли мне использовать database backup, и хранит 
ли оно всю информацию ?

Comment: А это зависит от того, как делать бэкап. Если снимать полный дамп (скажем, с помощью [mysqldump](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysqldump.html)) и не ограничивать в том, что дампить - да, всё копируется полностью. Кроме пользователей и прав - эти вещи находятся за пределами базы данных и копируются отдельно.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### основы

В понимании MySQL, обычно, под backup (или резервной копией) понимают набор инструкций, выполнив которые, MySQL сервер сможет восстановить полное состояние сервера или отдельных сущностей: баз(ы) данных, таблицы, строк и т.п.

В классической веб-разработке и при переносе данных с сервера на сервер, чаще всего, используется [mysqldump](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysqldump.html) или приложения (к примеру phpmyadmin, [adminer](https://www.adminer.org/)):

```
# - user - имя пользователя для подключения к серверу
# -p (--password=) - будет запрошен пароль (если он установлен)
#      можно указать пароль в командной строке
# - localhost - хост, имя mysql-сервера
# - database - имя базы данных для резервирования 

# указать пароль (не рекомендуется)
mysqldump --user=user --password=pasSw0rd --host=localhost database > dump.sql
# пароль будет запрошен
mysqldump --user=user -p --host=localhost database > dump.sql

# можно "сжать" дамп
# mysqldump --user=user --password=pasSw0rd --host=localhost database | gzip > dump.sql.gz
```

Эта команда сохранит полную копию базы данных (схему и данные) в файл `dump.sql`. SQL-дамп - это обычный текстовый файл, его можно открыть и посмотреть "что внутри".

Для восстановления, нужно скопировать файл на целевой сервер, и выполнить команду:

```
# user - пользователь для подключения к серверу
# localhost - имя mysql сервера
# 
mysql --user=user -p --host=localhost database < dump.sql
```

Можно выбирать различные опции при создании дампа/резервной копии, например:

- создавать базу данных если ее нет (нужны права)
- удалять/пересоздавать таблицы при восстановлении
- [и еще много чего](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysqldump.html#mysqldump-option-summary)...

### bonus

Можно копировать данные по сети, сразу с целевого сервера. Для этого должен быть ssh-доступ:

```
# src.me - источник, откуда копируем (пользователь user)

ssh user@src.me mysqldump -uuser -p -hlocalhost database | mysql -uuser -p -hlocalhost database
```

Если пароля нет, то `-p` не нужно указывать. Пароль можно указать прямо в строке, но это считается не безопасным. Если используется какое либо приложение, то обычно это опции import/export. На каждом хостинге существуют описания стандартных процедур резервирования и восстановления баз данных.

- **всегда при любых манипуляциях с важным данными сохраняйте резервные копии, которые отражают состояние системы до внесения изменений**
- mysqldump перезапишет целевую базу данных без каких либо вопросов, это надо учитывать
- если пользователь базы данных не совпадает на исходном и целевом серверах, то потребуется внести изменения в конфигурацию приложения

Comment: Добавьте в ответ опции `mysqldump ... --routines --triggers` иначе хранимые и триггеры окажутся за бортом

Comment: спасибо за дополнение. Но `--triggres` - это опция по-умолчанию, а `--routines` требует глобальной привилегии - `select`. Упоминания в комментарии вполне.